# Error creating GUI for SQL Server on Netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I am currently working on an SQL project, and I am making a GUI on Netbeans. I have found a code that someone used, and I wish to alter it around. However, I am currently getting an error that I don't know how to fix it. I have contacted the person who created this code, but I didn't get a response. The error I get after running my code is:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jbdc.SQLServerException: The method executeQuery() cannot take arguments on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement

Here is the portion of the code I copied

```
private void signinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQL2.cis245.mc3.edu:1433;\" + \"databaseName=zz_CIS245_16;user=tpatel;password=tpatel";   
            
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("connection created");
           
            String sql="select * from test where Username=? and Passeword=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, username.getText());
            pst.setString(2, password.getText());
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);

            if(rs.next())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "password and username matched");
                //System.out.println("Address : "+rs.getString(2));
            }
            else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"password or username not corrected");
            username.setText("");
            password.setText("");
            }
                con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);` to `ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();` - the statement is already defined when you call `prepareStatement`

Comment: Thank you for this. It did fix that message I was getting, but now I am getting a message that displays invalid object name 'test'.

Comment: Does the table `test` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, in SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You have already passed the query to the PreparedStatement variable here:

```
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Just remove the argument from exectuteQuery() method

```
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
```